# Nodejs - Mongodb - arrayFilters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, updates

I use mongodb in my nodejs application. I want update in my base json file.
Exemple: I have 3 notifications where I have read: false, If I execute my request I want Update this 3  notifications for read: true.

> But it's not work. I have this message (node:12884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters
>
> THANKS FOR YOUR HELPS!!!!!!!

**Model.js**

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
   username: { type: String, required: true, validate: usernameValidator },
   notifications: [{
      sender_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
      message: { type: String},
      viewProfile: { type: Boolean, default: false},
      created: { type: Date, default: Date.now()},
      read: { type: Boolean, default: false},
      date: { type: String, default: ''}
   }]
});
```

**notifiRoutes.js**

```
User.update(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    { $set: { "notifications.$[elem].read": true } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.read": false } ], multi: false }
)
```

*If the user have 10 notifications, where (read: false) and he clicked on the button on my siteweb, after this attribut read must updat his value for true, like this (read: true) for 10 notifications*